# Trouble with disabling internal keyboard in Ubuntu, although with no problem with Linux-Mint

Tags: keyboard, xinput

I have troublesome internal keyboard and while using Linux-mint previously I used to `sudo xinput float [slave_keyboard_ID]` to disable my internal keyboard.

But in Ubuntu, the trouble I face is the following:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadDevice (invalid Device parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Device id in failed request: 0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  18
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

What is the simplest way out? Thanks in advance.

---

The details of my current Ubuntu version:

```
 Static hostname: system
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: db03e28ec7144744a8cc42fa4e690db4
         Boot ID: 94934741906c48569a453842e0cb1953
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: Lenovo ideapad 300-15ISK
```

Comment: You've not provided any clear clues as to your software stack (ie. Ubuntu product & release), but given Linux Mint is a Ubuntu based system, I'd contrast what you know works (what *stack* is the Linux Mint you're using built on, what release, what kernel stack choice (GA or HWE for example) and contrast that with the Ubuntu system (ie. what release & what kernel stack as Ubuntu has multiple choices from GA, HWE & some OEM options)..   From that detail I'd expect to work out the difference & thus *fix* to your issue.  You've not provided specific details for us to provide clear advice though

Comment: yes I have updated the details

Comment: Thanks for adding details of one system, what is the Linux Mint using?   You've highlighted one is *jammy* (22.04) currently using the GA kernel stack (5.15), so what was the comparison Linux Mint system that you say produced different detail?  The easiest way to find answers (*in my opinion*) is to contrast the differences (*esp. given you have something that does what you want, and something that doesn't!*)

Comment: The fact that `it worked in Linux mint` is not what concerns me, rather what does, is that `it doesn't work` in the ubuntu release I'm currently in.

Comment: The fact that it worked in Linux Mint which is a Ubuntu based system will provide details on how to make it work in Ubuntu - which was my point.  You've provided no details on what you were using with Linux Mint, what Ubuntu was it based or or more specifically what kernel was it using (a Ubuntu GA or HWE kernel; using `uname -r` will provide the kernel details; kernel tells you what kernel modules (commonly called *drivers*).  Was Linux Mint using a different stack to 22.04 GA which is a starting point to getting it fixed.